# PHP bootstrap 4 Delete button does not fetch ID

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have done created delete button with confirmation box. However, it seems that the delete button does not work because it cannot transfer the id that i want to delete.

Table for Delete button:

```
 <tbody>
            <?php
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                {
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                    
                    <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['isAdmin']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="register_edit.php" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="edit_isAdmin" value="<?php echo $row['isAdmin']; ?>">
                        <button type="submit" name="edit_btn" class="btn btn-success"> EDIT </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button  type="button"  class="btn btn-danger delete_btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletemodal"> DELETE </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
            }
            else{
                echo"No Record Found";
            }
            ?>   
            </tbody>
```

code for the modal:

```
<form action="code.php" method="POST">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" id="delete_id" />
    <h4> Are you sure want to delete this data? </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="deletedata" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary delete_btn" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="" id="delete_id" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Script that i use :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.delete_btn').on('click',function(){
    $('#deletemodal').modal('show');  
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        console.log(data) ;
        $('#delete_id').val(data[0]);
    });
});

</script
```

Comment: Please share with us one or two rows of your HTML table

Comment: I have edited the post.Please refer the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your modal trigger button and attach a custom attribute and ID as its value.

```
<button  type="button"  class="btn btn-danger delete_btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletemodal" delete-id = "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> DELETE </button>
```

When you trigger the button read the value and write it in modal dialog's hidden input. This way you can access your id and proceed for further steps. update your modal form as below.

```
<form action="code.php" method="POST">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" id="delete_id" />
    <h4> Are you sure want to delete this data? </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="deletedata" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary delete_btn" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
    
  </div>
</form>
```

**`Your jquery will be like`**

```
$('.delete_btn').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('delete-id');
    $("#delete_id").val(id);

    $('#deletemodal').modal('show');  
        
        var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        console.log(data) ;
        $('#delete_id').val(data[0]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a usefull way for some people as well:

The button/div/span/url with data you want to delete:

```
<span class="deleteButton" data="DATA-YOU-WANT-TO-SEND" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDelete">click for delete</i></span>
```

**The 1st jQuery**

```
$(document).on( "click", ".deleteButton", function() {
    var string = $(this).attr('data');
    $('#item-record').attr('data-confirm',string);
});
```

Your button inside the (just opened) modal will get the data inside 'data-confirm':

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default DELETE-ITEM" data-dismiss="modal" id="item-record" data-confirm="">Yes, delete!</button>
```

Now you handle the request when DELETE-ITEM is confirmed

```
$(document).on( "click", ".DELETE-COMMENT", function() {
var yourData = $(this).attr('data-confirm');

$.ajax({
///DO YOUR STUFF
```